# mouse moved events are not detected by NSView

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am trying to make a simple application in which there is a empty red rectangle and whenever the mouse is moved over the upper half border of the rectangle the cursor will become closed hand.

I started with selecting the foundation command line project.Made a transparent `NSWindow` and embedded a `NSView` in it with the rectangle, made window to accept mouse moved events(by method: `-setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents`). I have overridden `-canBecomeKeyWindow` and `-canBecomeMainWindow` window to return YES. But somehow none of the `-mouseMoved` events are being received by `NSView`.

When I put the same code by making a cocoa application project and creating my window in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` method , my view was able to receive `-mouseMoved` events.

why is it not receiving mouse moved events when I use foundation command line utility project ?

I have also observed that whenever I make a window(carbon or cocoa) through foundation cmd line utility project , the window doesn't become key even on clicking the title bar.On clicking the title bar color remains light grey instead of becoming dark grey. Why is this happening?

I have overridden `-canBecomeKeyWindow` and `-canBecomeMainWindow` of `NSwindow` to return YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no event loop to detect events and pass them to your window because your program does not start an NSApplication. See the main.m file of a typical Cocoa application.

It might be helpful to describe what you're trying to accomplish by taking this approach. My guess is you're building a daemon but want a GUI interface to manage the otherwise "headless" daemon. That or you're building a new login management system. In either case, there are specific ways to do both and this isn't it. :-)

Comment: Joshua my view is able to recieve other events like mouseDown and mouseDragged.The only problem is receiving mousesMoved events. 

Actually I am working on migrating an application from carbon to cocoa.I cannot use interface builder and nib file as they were not used in the original carbon code.

I got stuck on this issue when I was trying to make a transparent capture window in which when user moves mouse over the border of the rectangle the mouse pointer should change to closedHand cursor depicting the user that he can move the window.

Comment: You said, "On clicking the title bar color remains light grey instead of becoming dark grey." The problem remains: you're not properly interfacing with the window server. A command line tool is not meant to do this. I'd further advise that you're far better off creating a new, normal Cocoa application and rebuild your app using the proper Cocoa design patterns. You're asking for a *world* of pain trying to do a straight "port" of a Carbon app by ramming your existing code down a command-line program's throat. This is worse than ill-advised.

Answer (score 13):

I would agree with what Joshua has already said. Any application that is going to show a user interface, be it a faceless background process or one which shows up in the Dock, should be in the form of an application bundle, not a plain old Mach-O executable like the Foundation tool template will create.

Also, there are reasons why views do not respond to `mouseMoved:` events by default:

1. Mouse moved events can quickly flood the event queue
2. There is generally little reason to use `mouseMoved:`, as tracking areas are
   far more effective and efficient.

A while back, I wrote a little test app that demonstrates the differences between these 2 approaches:

[image]

Moving your mouse around the upper view for roughly 20 seconds results in 1000 events, while in the lower view, which uses tracking areas, less than 50.

Sample GitHub project: https://github.com/NSGod/MouseMoved-vs-TrackingAreas

Again, as Joshua mentioned, it would be helpful if you could describe what you're trying to accomplish. If your app needs to be a background app (LSUIElement == 1), and present an interface without appearing in the Dock, then there are ways to do that (as Josh mentioned, a command-line, non-bundled app is not the way).